# Lights out - foobar - optimise python implementation beyond binary matrix solver

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for further details on solving 'Lights out' puzzle, as asked in foobar challenge. Sorry I don't have enough credit to add/comment on existing threads, but I'm interested in a specific numerical aspects to these:

failed brute force (python):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436275/how-can-i-further-optimize-this-solver-of-a-variant-of-lights-out

succeeded brute force (java):
[Minimal number of moves needed to solve a "Lights Out" variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052609/minimal-number-of-moves-needed-to-solve-a-lights-out-variant)

I have tried so far: last year I timed on this in python, invitation revoked, recently invitation reissued, requested puzzle and got this one *again*. First time around I got to basically all the same steps as the posters in above link, transformed problem into $M\times M$ matrix $A$ ($M=N^2$, $N=$size of puzzle) and solving $Ax=b$. Case for even N was simple, and I did the binary representation (pure python 2.7.6, no numpy or anything allowed in challenge) to solve for odd $N$. Bottleneck is finding the 'minimum weight' vector, which lives in a 28 dim subspace (Test 3 from 5 gets a timeout, which is at $N=15$ with dim kernel $A=28$). From above links I gather:

1) People have successfully implemented brute force looping over $2^{28}$ vectors in Java. In Python, I timeout even just looping over a completely empty loop of $2^{28}$, the max size I can loop over empty with 'for i in xrange($1<<K$)' is $K=2^{25}$. Would there be such a massive difference in time limit between Python and Java to make implementation of the former impossible? Anyone succeeded with Python?

2) I am at a loss if anyone has succeeded in finding a non brute force way (e.g. as alluded at end of 1st link above). Is there any symmetry in A I can exploit before I tackle solving for $Ax=b$? Or is that a dead end.

Failing the first time around was painful enough, but the second time it feels personal. I'd really appreciate any kind of hints or 'don't go there, dead end' to at least letting me have a decent go before I timeout again!

Comment: Small implementation details: why `2 ** ` instead of `<<`, `%2` instead of `&1` ? Why `current*n + j for j in xrange(n)` instead of `j for j in xrange(current*n,current*(n+1))` and so on. Does python optimize all it? Can one use a profiler?...

Comment: Yes, you can profile with your own 2.7.6 interpreter, but the 'virtual console' of the challenge is off limits. Unsure as to your other implementation comments - these must be to the referenced links, and yes, these guys have heavily optimised their Python code. Basically my question is: how can the actual 'coset weight' calculation (counting 1's in linear combinations of binary vectors) be made fast enough, if even a _completely empty loop_ over that search space times out 3 orders of magnitudes earlier. Any hints on symmetries in original puzzle to exploit?