# Minimize the sum of solution of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, gaussian-elimination

Let x(i,j) be a variable. All variables and constants can only have value of 0 or 1. Also, sum of two variables x(i,j) and x(k,l) is equal to `(x(i,j)+x(k,l)) % 2`   For a given equation of the following format, what algorithm can be used to find a solution to all x(i,j) such that sum of all x(i,j) is minimized:

```
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +0       +0       +x(2,0)  +0       +0       = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +0       +x(1,1)  +0       +0       +x(2,1)  +0       = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +0       +0       +x(1,2)  +0       +0       +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +0       +0       +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  +0       +0       = 0
0       +x(0,1)  +0       +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +0       +x(2,1)  +0       = 0
0       +0       +x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +0       +0       +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +0       +0       +x(1,0)  +0       +0       +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
0       +x(0,1)  +0       +0       +x(1,1)  +0       +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
0       +0       +x(0,2)  +0       +0       +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
```

The above equation can also be seen as:

```
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +x(2,0)  = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,1)  +x(2,1)  = 0
x(0,0)  +x(0,1)  +x(0,2)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  = 0
x(0,1)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,1)  = 0
x(0,2)  +x(1,0)  +x(1,1)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,0)  +x(1,0)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,1)  +x(1,1)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
x(0,2)  +x(1,2)  +x(2,0)  +x(2,1)  +x(2,2)  = 1
```

For example, the given equation can have following two solutions:

1. x(0,2)=x(1,0)=x(1,1)=1 and all x(i,j) = 0. In this case sum of all x(i,j) = 3
2. x(2,2)=1 and all x(i,j)=0. In this case sum of all x(i,j) is 1

What algorithm can be used to find later solution. I have tried using gausian elimination, but the result is not consistent.

**More explanation:**
More explanation on how the equation was obtained: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/441588/299278

**EDIT1:** I implemented a BFS for this but it is very inefficient for variables till x(15,15).

Comment: Your problem is a bit hard to understand. Perhaps you can clarify further? For example, what is that tableau?

Comment: Added a link to the question explaining how the equations are obtained

Comment: Each row in the table is an equation

Comment: This could be solved with MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) solvers using a dummy objective.

Comment: I have never heard of MIP before. while I am researching about this, can you help me with this problem and add an answer?

Comment: I will make it an answer as I need a little bit more space.

Comment: this is exactly a SAT problem (which is a subclass of integer programming which is indeed equivalent to it, every IP can be reduced to a SAT problem) and in general (many variables, many equations, all with 'random' 0/1 coefficients) to say if there is a solution as to find one is NP-complete.

Comment: and the general algorithm to solve integer programming problems is [branch and cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_cut) which uses relaxed constraints (for example instead of $0/1$ it allows $x_i \in [0;1]$ and then using normal linear programming) and thus the idea to use gaussian elimination was not so idiot as it can at least give us ways to eliminate impossible solutions.  of course, when the variable domains are finite, integer programming can also be solved by simply trying all the solutions, but this will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for the game as specified in your link. I use a Mixed Integer Program (MIP) to model the problem. This can be solved using any MIP solver.

Basically we count the number of switches in the same row and column and require that the final state is even (to make it dark). (Note: the sum is over the whole column and the over the whole row, so we double count the element itself -- this is repaired by the subtraction). Even means 2 times an arbitrary integer. I said earlier to use a dummy objective. We can however even minimize the number of switches.

I use the initial state $s0$:

[image]

The model can be compactly written as:

[image]

The *even* constraint is basically what you described in your question. My $s_{i,j}$ is your $x_{i,j}$. In the model we use a binary variable $s_{i,j}$ which can only assume values 0 or 1. The integer variable $y_{i,j}$ is used only to make sure the final state is $0,2,4,...$.

When I solve this I see one would need to apply the following switches:

```
----     37 VARIABLE s.L  switch state

            c1          c2          c3          c4

r1           1                                   1
r2           1           1           1
r3                       1                       1
r4                                   1           1
```

Note: you can solve MIP models like this remotely on [NEOS](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html). The complete GAMS model is [here](http://www.amsterdamoptimization.com/models/lightsout.gms). (GAMS is the modeling language I used to express the model).