# Looking for solution to "lights out" puzzle variant with multiple states

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

Recently in World of Warcraft, there is a [puzzle](https://www.wowhead.com/guides/the-hivemind#yellow-monocle-halls-of-origination) that is very similar to the "lights out" puzzle where a player needs to flip switches to turn all the lights into a specific color (in this case yellow, green, red, white). I have seen other solution to the lights out problem using [linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441571/lights-out-variant-flipping-the-whole-row-and-column) however all these uses only 2 states (on or off).

I haven't ever ran into a system of linear equation with modular operation before and would like some help solving something like:

```
  L_1 = ((s_1 + s_2 + ...s_n + c_1 ) mod 4)

  L_2 = ((s_1 + s_2 + ...s_n + c_2 ) mod 4)

           ...

  L_n = ((s_1 + s_2 + ...s_n + c_n ) mod 4)
```

where each L has some linear combination of s + constant mod 4

Comment: It will be a bit different mod 4 because 2 doesn't have a modular inverse, so mod 4 doesn't form a field.  But you can still do gaussian elimination on the matrix, just do all the adding and mulitplying mod 4 and try hard to pick odd numbers to make into pivots.

Comment: See the 2017 [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.124.10.937) _"Lights Out" and Variants_ by Martin Kreh in the _American Mathematical Monthly_ which specifically treats modular colors on square grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the mod 4 version like two instances of the mod 2 version.

First treat states $1$ and $3$ as if they are switched-on lights, and states $0$ and $2$ as if they are switched-off lights. Solve this as the normal lights out. You are essentially just working mod $2$, making everything even. At the end of this stage, all lights are either $0$ or $2$.

Then solve the rest as another two-state lights out puzzle, where $2$ is the switched-on state and $0$ is a switched-off state. The only difference is that the moves you do consist of double button presses. A double button press skips over the $1$ and $3$ states, and toggles lights between the $0$ and $2$ state.