# Strategy to zerofy a matrix

Tags: algorithms, combinations, discrete-optimization

I am considering an interesting question, given an $\{0,1\}$-matrix $M \in \{0,1\}^{n\times p}$, we define that an **k-operation** to the matrix is changing value of $M$ to be $\tilde{M}$ such that
$$ \tilde{M}_{ij}=\begin{cases}
 0, &  i \in\{1,\ldots,n\}\text{,and } j \in\{l\in\{1,\ldots,n\}|M_{kl}=1\} \\
 M_{ij} ,& \text{otherwise.} \\
\end{cases}
$$
We renew $M$ with $\tilde{M}$, operation finished.

A k-operation is essentially putting all columns that has the $k$th row element 1 to be $\boldsymbol{0}$.

The question is how to pick **minimum number of** the ***k*** s to do operations such that $M$ becomes the zero matrix (which is the matrix with all entries $0$)?

My idea is each step picking the $k$ which flips most number of $1$s to become $0$ in a greedy way. However, I could not prove this, could someone please help me with it?

Comment: I don't *think* that's the same variant, but "$\forall i \in\{1,\ldots,n\},\, j \in\{l\in\{1,\ldots,n\}|M_{kl}=1\}$" is really the sort of thing best explained in words.

Comment: Your operation is not well-defined. You said:

$$ \tilde{M}_{ij}=\begin{cases}
 0, & \forall i \in\{1,\ldots,n\},\, j \in\{l\in\{1,\ldots,n\}|M_{kl}=1\} \\
 M_{ij} ,& \text{otherwise.} \\
\end{cases}
$$

In the first case on the right-hand side, $i$ is universally quantified. However, on the left-hand side, $i$ represents a (fixed) arbitrary index.

Comment: Thank you @MishaLavrov, I made a line to explain the operation.

Comment: Thank you @diracdeltafunk, I did a rectification.

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt, but I think that may not help that much for this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lights Out Variant: Flipping the whole row and column.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441571/lights-out-variant-flipping-the-whole-row-and-column)

Comment: @Sebastiano I initially had the same thought, but it’s not the same.

Comment: @RobPratt Ok. Thank you for your adivce.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the lights out question. This one does not treat rows and columns the same, and this one does not toggle from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the [set cover problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), and greedy is not optimal.